# Dynamic Programming: find the minimal route with ten nodes from a set of 100 nodes

Tags: dynamic-programming

You are given 100 stations and distance between each adjacent stations. Now you have to select 10 stations(means 10 hops) among those 100 stations in such a way that maximum of distance between any 2 hops will be minimised. By default 1 and 100 stations are selected , so you need to choose only 8 more stations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't told us:

- I'll assume time isn't an issue
- I'll assume memory isn't an issue.
- I'll assume the answer isn't programming language specific
- I'll assume you are aiming to get from one station (1) to a destination station (100)

> ```
> //Iterate through all possible paths to destination
>
> //If you take more than 8 steps, stop and go back
>
> //Note the total length of each path
>
> //Select the shortest path
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are being asked a question for an interview and then want us to give it to you to reiterate to an employer.  It is pretty easy though, i have a similar program on my home pc implementing a few different path finding techniques.

Comment: this is better as a comment than an answer (since it isn't an answer).

Comment: While I agree with you hatchet, you can't comment on SOF until you reach a certain amount of reputation. So he could have just been compelled enough to comment even if it had to be posted as an answer. :)

Comment: @James - just trying to help him avoid the downvotes I often seen this type of "answer" collect.

Comment: Yeah, I gotcha. I was just pointing out why he probably posted it as an answer instead, cause I was in the exact situation many times before my reputation was high enough to comment, it sucked. lol